# How to scrape the number using querySelector or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="&quot;active&quot; active">
   <input type="radio" name="contact_4840" value="0gc_-GtRsdeddeffgT4xniw" checked="&quot;checked&quot;">XXX-XXX-2135
</div>
```

I want to scrape ***XXX-XXX-2135*** using `querySelector JavaScript`.

```html
<div class="&quot;active&quot; active">
  <input type="radio" name="contact_4840" value="0gc_-GtR9EuUiDZvT4xniw" checked="&quot;checked&quot;">
  XXX-XXX-2135
</div>
```

Comment: any specific reason to revert my answer as accepted? I saw initially you accepted my one after some time you changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this way with [Node.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) to grab the inner text of the selected element that you select using `querySelector()`

```js
let elm = document.querySelector('.active');
console.log(elm.innerText);
```

```html
<div class="&quot;active&quot; active">
  <input type="radio" name="contact_4840" value="0gc_-GtR9EuUiDZvT4xniw" checked="&quot;checked&quot;">
  XXX-XXX-2135
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.active').textContent.trim());
```

```html
<div class="active">
  <input type="radio" name="contact_4840" value="0gc_-GtR9EuUiDZvT4xniw" checked="&quot;checked&quot;">
  XXX-XXX-2135
</div>
```